# Добавление строк в таблицы SQL

Tags: sql

Как правильно добавить строку в таблицу SQL если есть вторая таблица связанная с первой по полю с Auto_incrimetn

при попытке добавления запросом пишет ошибку 
Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test_app`.`tests_iq_question`, CONSTRAINT `tests_iq_question_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`question_id`) REFERENCES `tests_iq_answers` (`Id_question`))

Comment: @валах вероятно, вы пытаетесь добавить в первую таблицу запись с внешним ключом, которого нет во второй таблице

Answer (score 1):

Судя по названиям столбцов, могу предположить, что вы создали внешний ключ не в той таблице. Полагаю, что внешний ключ должен быть в ответах, и ссылаться он должен на вопросы, а не наоборот.